# How to return a boolean after inserting within a postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a table named `member`. I want to create a function that inserts a new email if it doesn't exist in the table, and then return a boolean.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  add_member(member_email TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
  $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM "community".member WHERE email = $1) THEN
            INSERT INTO "community".member (email) VALUES ($1) RETURNING TRUE;
        ELSE
            RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT add_member('cheese.head@green.org');
```

I get this error `ERROR:  query has no destination for result data`.
Is the `INSERT` not returning the expected data? Or wrapping it in another data type? Is this how you use the `INSERT` with the returning?

Comment: read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Comment: Read [Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW). You need to `DECLARE` a variable to hold the `RETURN` of the insert.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok. I think I get it. The docs are a pretty dense to me. I'll keep at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `INSERT ... RETURNING ... INTO` from here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  add_member(member_email TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
  $$
    DECLARE
        return_val BOOLEAN := FALSE;
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM "community".member WHERE email = $1) THEN
            INSERT INTO "community".member (email) VALUES ($1) RETURNING TRUE INTO return_val;
       
        END IF;
    RETURN return_val;
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

`DECLARE` the `return_val` variable as `boolean` and with default value of `FALSE`. Then do test for existing value and if present do `INSERT` and update the `return_val` variable with the `TRUE` returning value from the insert. Then `RETURN return_val` which will be `FALSE` if an existing `member_email` is found and `TRUE` if one is not found.

Comment: I have a separate but related question. If I want to return not just the value but a 'TABLE' with Columns 'email TEXT, new_member BOOLEAN', is that a bit of a stretch?

Comment: Then create a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 1):

read the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

just do this in 2 statements.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
  add_member(member_email TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
  $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT email FROM "community".member WHERE email = $1) THEN
            INSERT INTO "community".member (email) VALUES ($1);
            RETURN TRUE;
        ELSE
            RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;
    END;
  $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

or

Read [Executing a Command with a Single-Row Result](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).

You need to DECLARE a variable to hold the RETURN of the insert.